# How to Keep the HTML formatted data as a body of java mail using java mail API?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-mail

I need to mail the xml validation Reports as a HTML content mail.
How to keep the below detailed information(derived from a parent class)as a HTML body using java mail api.
//Exact Requirement: 
TITLE :                    CAR Validation Report
//Background color : orange
//Font color : Black
1.Total No of Errors   : 12
2.Total No of Warnings : 150

CAR Validation Successful.

My java code for mail:

```
MimeMessage message = new     
MimeMessage(session);                                   
                m_toterr=validatexml.Total_err;
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));   
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new 
InternetAddress(to1));
                //message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new  
InternetAddress(to2));
                //message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new 
InternetAddress(to3));
                //message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new 
InternetAddress(to4));
                message.setSubject("RE : CAR Validation Report of : 
"+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())); 
                message.addHeaderLine("line");
                MimeHeader header1=new MimeHeader("Content-
Type","test/html");
                MimeBodyPart line0 =new MimeBodyPart();
                MimeBodyPart line1 = new MimeBodyPart();
                MimeBodyPart line2 = new MimeBodyPart();
                MimeBodyPart line3 = new MimeBodyPart();
                MimeBodyPart line4 = new MimeBodyPart();
                MimeBodyPart line5 = new MimeBodyPart();
                MimeBodyPart line6 = new MimeBodyPart();
                MimeBodyPart line7 = new MimeBodyPart();


                Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();  


                   System.out.println("Total number of Errors at console 
from mailer:"+m_toterr);
                   //CarParser1.logger.info("Total number of 
Errors:"+m_toterr);
                  line0.setContent("<body bgcolor=yellow>","text/html");
                  line1.setContent("<h4 style=color:blue>Dear 
All,</h4>","text/html");
                  line2.setContent("<br><br><h4 style=color:red>The     
below is the today's CAR Validation status</h4>","text/html");

                  line3.setContent("</p>","text/html");
                  line4.setContent("</body>","text/html");


                  //line3.setContent("<br><h4 style=color:blue>PFA for 
the Log File</h4>","text/html");
                  //line4.attachFile("D:/logfile.log");
                  line4.setContent("<br><br><h4 style=color:blue>   
Regards,<br>( E-ops Software ) </h5>","text/html");
                  line5.setContent("<br><h4 style=color:red>(Auto mail, 
please do not reply)</h4>","text/html");
             //     line7.setContent("System.out.println(Total Number of 
errors:"+m_toterr);");

                  multipart.addBodyPart(line0);
                  multipart.addBodyPart(line1);
                  multipart.addBodyPart(line2);
                  //multipart.addBodyPart(line3);
                  multipart.addBodyPart(line4);
                  multipart.addBodyPart(line5);
                //  multipart.addBodyPart(line6);

                message.setContent(multipart );
                Transport.send(message);

                System.out.println("Email Sent successfully....");
                CarParser1.logger.info("Email Sent Successfully...");
                System.out.println();
            }
```

--------------code ends

please help.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MaklQ.png

Comment: please click on above link to get the sample mail screen shot

Comment: Unclear. Is the link the expected result or the current result?

Comment: sorry.Its just a reference and the exact requirement is above mentioned.

Comment: I need the log mail report as like as the file attached and that is only a format ,content and code are above.please help.

Comment: Can you post the current result?

Comment: CAR Validation Log report.
Total Number of Errors:12
Total Number of Warnings :150

CAR Validation Success...!!!
or CAR Validation Failure...!!!

Comment: These are all i need it as a html email with background color

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't really understand you.  
I suggest that you take the time and find a way to explain your issue in order for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the data into a single String with html markup, using whatever technique you prefer, then set that String as the content of a single MimeBodyPart.  You definitely **do not** want a part for each line.

Comment: String htmlBody = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Page Title</title>"

Comment: + "Total Number of Warnings :&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</td></tr>"
           + "<tr><td>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;"
           + "Total Number of Skipped

Comment: message.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");

Comment: Thank you .You saved my time and energy.it helped me really and i have done as above and it works for me..